# Subject of Observables in Inheritence Typescript

Tags: angular, inheritance, observable, angular-observable

I was using Subject and Observable in Typescript in Inheritence.

Their is Base Class -

```
class Animals{
   val: string = 'not present';
   val1: string= 'not present 1'; 
   subject: Subject<string> = new Subject();  

   data = Observable.create(obs => {
        obs.next('Ohla ! me created');
      })
  constructor(){
       this.subject.subscribe(data=>this.val = data)
       this.subject.subscribe(data=>this.val1 = data)
    }
}
```

This is Inherited Class

```
class Horse extends Animals {
   val2: string = 'not present 3';

  constructor(){

        super();
        this.subject.subscribe(data=> this.val2 = data);
        this.data.subscribe(this.subject);   
    }
}
```

As the Expected result would be that -

```
 val='Ohla ! me created';
 val1='Ohla ! me created';
 val2='Ohla ! me created';
```

The Problem is - val and val1 is only accessible to TS file.
I am not getting in UI i.e in HTML `{{val}} {{val1}}` here default value takes place.

Any Help would appreciated .